# Running the basic .NET Core MVC App on SSL, HTTPS inside Docker Container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, dockerfile, asp.net-core-2.0

I am learning how to run my .net core web applications on docker (on windows host) with SSL. I started with the basic application that .net core gives by doing "dotnet new mvc".

Then I moved ahead and modified the code inside Program.cs to listen only on port 443.

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseKestrel(options =>
            {
                options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 443, listenOptions =>
                {
                    listenOptions.UseHttps("test.com.pfx", "1234");
                });
            })
            .Build();
}
```

I created s self signed certificate and mentioned the password. Please ignore the way the password is exposed as I am still doing this as a POC.

Then I modified my dockerfile as:

> FROM microsoft/dotnet
>
> WORKDIR /app
>
> COPY bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/publish .
>
> EXPOSE 443
>
> ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "dotnetssl.dll"]

Now If I build and run the image with:

> docker build -t httpssample .
>
> docker run -it -p 443:443 httpssample

I am not able to access the website with the URL https://localhost , also I get below lines printed in the console:

> warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
>         No XML encryptor configured. Key {9f9e447d-d766-4a7d-9413-03466512b7a9} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
>   warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
>         Unable to bind to http://localhost:5000 on the IPv6 loopback interface: 'Error -99 EADDRNOTAVAIL address not available'.
>   Hosting environment: Production
>   Content root path: /app
>   Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
>   Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

Comment: What is the `IPAddress` value if you run `docker inspect httpssample`?

Comment: @JamieTaylor I ran this command but this doen't lists any IP address.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? Do you have a github repo where I could see the final result?